# AutoMapper from DataTable to DTO

Tags: ado.net, .net-4.6.1, automapper-6

I have a `DataSet` populated during an ADO.NET call which I want to then use AutoMapper to convert to a DTO.

I have defined a generic-use mapper for many of our DTO types:

```
IMapper DataReaderMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddDataReaderMapping();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyApp>();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyRole>();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyBill>();
}).CreateMapper();
```

This works great when mapping for all of these DTO types:

```
var apps = DataReaderMapper.Map<IList<AppDTO>>(dataSet.Tables[0].CreateDataReader());
```

However, I have now added this mapping:

```
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, Money>();
```

However, this `Money` type contains two `float` properties which appear to be giving AutoMapper some issues, with this exception:

> Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: IDataReader -> Money System.Data.IDataReader ->
> Common.Models.Money
>
> Type Map configuration: IDataReader -> Money System.Data.IDataReader
> -> Common.Models.Money
>
> Destination Member:
>
> Amount

Which contains this `InnerException`:

> Specified cast is not valid.

I have tried specifying a custom value mapping:

```
cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, Money>().ForMember(x => x.Amount, opt => opt.MapFrom(rdr => Convert.ToDouble(rdr["Amount"])));
```

But this is not even changing the exception.

How can I tell AutoMapper that this `Money` type should have its `float Amount` property populated by converting from the SQL field `float Amount`?

Comment: Try https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @lucian-bargaoanu for the link. This prompted me to take another look at the documentation which resulted in providing a resolver.

I have now fleshed out the mappings with some custom resolvers:

```
IMapper DataReaderMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddDataReaderMapping();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyApp>();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyRole>();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyBill>();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, Money>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Amount, opt => opt.MapFrom<MoneyAmountResolver>())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.SubTotal, opt => opt.MapFrom<MoneySubTotalResolver>());
}).CreateMapper();
```

The resolvers are just small classes:

```
public class MoneyAmountResolver: IValueResolver<IDataReader, Money, float>
{
    public float Resolve(IDataReader source, Moneydestination, float member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return (float)Convert.ToDouble(source["Amount"]);
    }
}

public class MoneySubTotalResolver: IValueResolver<IDataReader, Money, float>
{
    public float Resolve(IDataReader source, Moneydestination, float member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return (float)Convert.ToDouble(source["SubTotal"]);
    }
}
```